# How to verify that a spring-boot web server is running

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am writing an integration test for a spring-boot web server

I want to use junit-jupiter (junit5) to check if the server is running using `Assumptions.assumeTrue` so that the test do not fail if the server is not running...

There seems not to be any API support for such operation, but can it be achieved in some other way? Pinging the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `actuator` module in spring boot. It will provide you with a health check URL and you could make a call to this URL and verify that it returns healthy.

Now that that is out of the way, if you need the server to be running while running your tests, you should probably be using the spring boot test runner, instead of using the JUnit runner. In this case you could still mock some of your spring beans and achieve the same kind of test, but with a spring context running alongside your tests. The downside of this is the overhead of needing to spin up the spring context before running tests, but if you need to use the actual web server, then this is what you should be doing.

Comment: The actuator is a brilliant suggestion. Thx! I tried to use a `@SpringBootTest`, but I get an error when trying to reference the `@SpringBootApplication` java file as it is a standalone server and not in the same project I am working on...